# Android Source: How to unpack files and edit source code

Tags: android

I have downloaded the Android source code by following the steps given here http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
I see that there are a lot of .pack files and I understand this contains the source code files,

My question is how do I unpack these files and actually edit/read the source code? can someone help?

I tried "git unpack-objects

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source files are not in .pack files, they are java and .cpp files
Most probably your download was not complete

Comment: Thanks, it's been a whole day and it's still downloading and has taken 5.5 Gb of space.. wondering why is the codebase so big (and still no .cpp and .java files either)

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep. btw, the whole process took me almost a day. This is what I observed, when I did 'repo sync' it downloaded 5.5g of information mostly in .pack files. After download, it checked-out files and .pack files disappeared. Now the source takes 2.8G (for android 2.3.4_r1) Thanks for the support...